# I would like to simulate gravitation between particles, but I think I forgot something?

Tags: math, three.js

So, for each star, i compare this one to all other stars to calculate his speed, velocity, etc.
But that didn't work, I'm not too strong in maths and I think my formula is maybe wrong? idk why that didn't work here my code :

```
//for each star I compare to all other stars
for(let i = 0; i < pos.length; i ++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < pos.length; j ++){
        if (i !== j){
            // Formula part
            const vector = compute_interaction(pos[i], pos[j], 1.0);
            accelerations[i].x += vector.x;
            accelerations[i].y += vector.y;
            accelerations[i].z += vector.z;
            break;
        }
    }

}
for (let i = 0 ; i<accelerations.length ; i++){
    speedStars[i].x += accelerations[i].x * 0.001;
    speedStars[i].y += accelerations[i].y * 0.001;
    speedStars[i].z += accelerations[i].z * 0.001;
}
for (let i = 0 ; i<speedStars.length ; i++){
    const i3 = i*3;
    starsPositions[i3] += speedStars[i].x * 0.001;
    starsPositions[i3 + 1] += speedStars[i].y * 0.001;
    starsPositions[i3 + 2] += speedStars[i].z * 0.001;
}

function compute_interaction(currentPosition, positionOtherStar, smoothing_length)
{
    const vector = new THREE.Vector3(positionOtherStar.x - currentPosition.x, positionOtherStar.y - currentPosition.y, positionOtherStar.z - currentPosition.z).normalize();
    let x = vector.x / (Math.pow(positionOtherStar.x,2.0) - Math.pow(currentPosition.x,2.0)+ smoothing_length)
    let y = vector.y / (Math.pow(positionOtherStar.y,2.0) - Math.pow(currentPosition.y,2.0)+ smoothing_length)
    let z = vector.z / (Math.pow(positionOtherStar.z,2.0) - Math.pow(currentPosition.z,2.0)+ smoothing_length)
    return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```

Here the CodePen: https://codepen.io/n0rvel/pen/ExEXbYN?editors=0010

Here is the formula/code logic I found on one OpenCL program that works:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a good effort so far. Looks like you are calculating acceleration and then integrating twice to get position, seems right. Two potential problems I see. (1) I think you need to set `acceleration[i]` equal to (0, 0, 0) before adding up the interaction terms. (2) You want to skip the interaction of star i with itself, so `if (i !== j) ...` makes sense, but I don't think you want `break` in there -- isn't that going to stop the loop on the first iteration? Good luck and keep up the good work.

Comment: PS. (3) Looks like `compute_interaction` is incomplete. The acceleration for a star is going to be `a = F/m`, right? where `m` is the star's mass and `F` is the force due to gravity, `F = G m[i] m[j] / (distance**2)` where `G` is the universal gravitational constant. So calculating `a` must involve `m[j]` (you don't need `m[i]` since it cancels out), but I don't see `m[j]` anywhere.

Comment: You're right I deleted the "break" :)
For the G and M, it's because I replace it by 1 to simplify, so a = 1/distance**2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming; it's a lack of knowledge of physics.

Comment: Too many magic numbers.  What's that 0.001 I see everywhere?  I would do some reading about numerical integration of systems of differential equations.  There is some involved math involved.  It's not possible to do well without knowing something about the math.  I'd recommend finding a library to help you.

Comment: lol calm duffymo, the "magic numbers" are the time step of the simulation

Comment: IT WORKS perfeclty now !

Comment: Yes, I get it.  Most integration schemes will vary the time step.  You probably didn't do anything like Fourier analysis to figure out what an appropriate time step would be.  Time step stability depends on integration scheme.  Looks like you're using explicit Euler integration, which is simple but means a very small time step limitation for stability.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I did. I didn't explain it initially it's hard to guess just by looking at the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the `compute_interaction()` function should be:

```
function compute_interaction(currentPosition, positionOtherStar, smoothing_length)
{
    //const vector = new THREE.Vector3(positionOtherStar.x - currentPosition.x, positionOtherStar.y - currentPosition.y, positionOtherStar.z - currentPosition.z).normalize();
    //let x = vector.x / (Math.pow(positionOtherStar.x,2.0) - Math.pow(currentPosition.x,2.0)+ smoothing_length)
    //let y = vector.y / (Math.pow(positionOtherStar.y,2.0) - Math.pow(currentPosition.y,2.0)+ smoothing_length)
    //let z = vector.z / (Math.pow(positionOtherStar.z,2.0) - Math.pow(currentPosition.z,2.0)+ smoothing_length)
    //return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);

    const vector = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(positionOtherStar, currentPosition);
    return vector.normalize().divideScalar(vector.lengthSq() + smoothing_length);
}
```

Comment: I applied your solution, I had to reset the acceleration, and now it works : https://codepen.io/n0rvel/pen/ExEXbYN?editors=0010